# Instant showing of review tasks

Tags: feature-request, review

For new questions and the chat there is the functionality showing (1) in the tab if there is  a new question or a new chat message. I'd like to suggest such a functionality for the review queue, either one for all review tasks or seperate ones for all of them.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you suggest that (1) should appear on the review page if a user has it open as a new item arrives? (So the user would not [end up in a webcomic](http://xkcd.com/281/))

Comment: @PavelM Yes, that is what I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has since been implemented by the userscript [Review Stalker](https://stackapps.com/q/4086/).

For those who prefer not to install a userscript, I wrote a [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC) with similar functionality. Having opened the review page, click the bookmarklet: the review count will be shown in the tab, and updated every 60 seconds. (Tip: open review queues in a new tab, so that the bookmarklet will keep on running.)

There are a few other [review-related scripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script+review) on Stack Apps. Given that this functionality is of interest only to "power users", it is unlikely that SE will implement it natively.

---

Uncompressed bookmarklet code:

```
t=document.title;
f();
function f() {
  r=new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.responseType='document';
  r.onload=function(e) {
    c=0;
    x=e.currentTarget.responseXML;
    a=x.querySelectorAll('.dashboard-item');
    for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
      c+=parseInt(a[i].children[0].innerText,10);
    }
  document.title='('+c+') '+t;
  document.getElementById('content').outerHTML=x.getElementById('content').outerHTML;
  window.setTimeout(f,60000);
  };
  r.open('GET',window.location.href,true);
  r.send();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to bump this thread, but the code above is  Chrome-specific. The new version, [posted here](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#review), works in both Chrome and Firefox (at least).