# Highlight Pending Reviews

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I recently started reviewing posts on Math.SE. However, whenever I go to the review page, most of the time it shows that there is nothing to review. I need to keep refreshing the page and keep looking if there is something to review. This is so inconvenient and causes me to take a lot of pains to do a single review task.

So I have a feature request that there be some sort of indication on the main page about the pending reviews tasks whenever there are any so that we do not have to go and look at the review page every minute.

---

**EDIT:** This is after this question has been closed. It has been marked duplicate of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/instant-showing-of-review-tasks) question and it says that this question already has an answer. However, the question *does not* have an answer and hardly any comments. So could someone explain how the closure is jusitified?

Comment: Such a feature is already available for "Suggested edits" once you have 10K reputation.

Comment: MSO threads: [168354](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168354/222340), [191638](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638/222340), [180868](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180868/222340).

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? If people like it, they upvote your post and/or Julian's (I did on both)...

Comment: I agree with draks, from my point of view there is no need for a second identical feature-request. This way just the votes are split. I also upvoted your request. Also answers can be put on either question.

Comment: @draks I am wondering why the earlier question did not receive much attention and there has been no explanation as to why the feature request has not been implemented.

Comment: true, but there are currently [only 21 implemented features that are posted here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+feature-request)...